# Twilio - Keep connecting of video chat when refreshing the browser

Tags: twilio

I am implementing video chat with Twilio JS on React. I have a question that while user reload their browser how to keep video connected state？
I referred to the https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react but still have no idea.

Comment: Hi hsu, maybe prevent the user to reload their brower :) ?

Comment: Thanks, Manu Eidenberger!  That's a good idea!